# Node.js inherits

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm doing a REST API using node with hapijs. So, I have to use inherits and I haven't success to access father's functions. I have this:

controller.js

```
var __ = require('underscore');

var Controller = function(){
    var Validator = require('../validators/'+this.controller);
    Controller.prototype.validate = new Validator();
}

Controller.prototype.returnErrors = function(err){
    var errors = [];
    __.each(err, function(error){
        errors.push(error.message);
    });
    return errors;
}

module.exports = Controller;
```

reckon.js

```
var __ = require('underscore'),
    reckon = require('../components/reckon'),
    inherits = require('util').inherits,
    Controller = require('./controller'),
    Reckon = require('../models/reckon').Reckon;

var ReckonCtr = function() {
    this.controller = "reckon";
    ReckonCtr.super_.call(this);
}

inherits(ReckonCtr, Controller);

ReckonCtr.prototype.get = function (request, reply, server, callback) {
   this.validate.get(__.extend({company:request.params.company}, request.query), function(validation, value){
       if(validation.error){
          return callback(this.returnErrors(validation.error.details));
       }
       reckon.getReckon(request.params.company, request.query, function(error, success){
           if(error) return callback(error);

           return callback(null, success);
       });
   });
}
module.exports = new ReckonCtr();
```

Why I can access "this.validate" and can't "this.returnErrors"? (TypeError: Uncaught error: Object # has no method 'returnErrors').

And how about turn my returnErrors private?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scoping problem.

You can access `this.validate` because you are in the context of the `ReckonCtr.prototype.get` method in which `this` refers to the instance. However, when you attempt to access `this.returnErrors` you are in the context of the callback of `this.validate.get` where `this` no longer points to the instance.

The simplest, most common, way around this problem is to take a reference to `this` as a local variable and refer to the variable rather than `this` directly e.g.

```
ReckonCtr.prototype.get = function (request, reply, server, callback) {
    var self = this;
    self.validate.get(__.extend({company:request.params.company}, request.query), function(validation, value){
       if(validation.error){
           return callback(self.returnErrors(validation.error.details));
       }
       reckon.getReckon(request.params.company, request.query, function(error, success){
           if(error) return callback(error);

           return callback(null, success);
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: And how about turn "private" my returnErrors function? Add an underscore and block access to "_"functions at my routes file?

Comment: @PopoKakedo do you mean making `returnErrors` only accessible from within `ReckonCtr`? There are many ways of doing this, if you can provide a little more context I could probably give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

`this.validate` is being used in a context where `this` refers to the `ReckonCtr` object so it works. In the callback, `this` does not refer to `ReckonCtr`.

Confusion over [what exactly `this` refers to in a given context](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) is a big problem in JavaScript. There are several solutions. This list is no doubt incomplete:

- In a function that contains the callback function, save a reference to `this` with something like `var self = this;` and then use `self` in the callback rather than `this`.
- If you're on a recent version of Node, you can use fat arrow syntax to make `this` more predictable.
- Use `bind()`, `call()`, or `apply()` to explicitly set the value of `this`.
- If the object you want is a singleton, just use the object explicitly rather than `this`.